# Get some details about external sort in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Reading this [article](http://www.dalibo.org/_media/understanding_explain.pdf) I found the following example:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY c1;
```

The plan of the query is this:

```
Sort  (cost=172682.84..175182.84 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=584.215..681.531 rows=1000000 loops=1)
  Sort Key: c1
  Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 45928kB
  Buffers: shared hit=3197 read=5137, temp read=5741 written=5741
  ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..18334.00 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=0.036..91.914 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=3197 read=5137
Total runtime: 711.195 ms
```

[As known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting), **external sort** is a family of algorithms. Does it mean that `PostgreSQL` does `external merge sort`? If so, how can I get some details, e.g. number of batches, and their size. Is it even possible?

Comment: You need to look into the source code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is that the only way? PosgtrSQL doesn't provide verbose information about algorithms it uses, does it?

Comment: It can't get any more verbose than the actual implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information in log file by setting parameter `trace_sorts=on` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-developer.html)

Besides, you may want to look into [src/backend/utils/sort/tuplesort.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/sort/tuplesort.c), at least at this comment:

> This module handles sorting of heap tuples, index tuples, or single
>   Datums (and could easily support other kinds of sortable objects,
>   if necessary).  It works efficiently for both small and large amounts
>   of data.  Small amounts are sorted in-memory using qsort().  Large
>   amounts are sorted using temporary files and a standard external sort
>   algorithm.
>
> See Knuth, volume 3, for more than you want to know about the external
>   sorting algorithm.  We divide the input into sorted runs using replacement
>   selection, in the form of a priority tree implemented as a heap
>   (essentially his Algorithm 5.2.3H), then merge the runs using polyphase
>   merge, Knuth's Algorithm 5.4.2D.  The logical "tapes" used by Algorithm D
>   are implemented by logtape.c, which avoids space wastage by recycling
>   disk space as soon as each block is read from its "tape".
>
> ...

Comment: Yeah, you caught exactly what I wanted. Thank you, espsecially for pointing out the sources.